# how can I count the status

Tags: mysql

I have this table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `table_detail` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `status` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    `dateTime_updated` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB

;
```

I want to count the user status having 7,6 and 4 with specified
query datetime from `2015-09-07 06:00:00 - 2015-09-11 20:00:00`

7=active,6=inactive,4 = deleted

expected output

```html
+---------+--------+----------+---------+
| user_id | active | inactive | deleted |
+---------+--------+----------+---------+
|      55 |      2 |        3 |       0 |
|      26 |      4 |        6 |       3 |
|      15 |      3 |        7 |       7 |
|      24 |      6 |        3 |       3 |
+---------+--------+----------+---------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this. All you need to do is add a `SUM(condition)` column in your select clause, and group by the `user_id` value like this:

```
SELECT user_id, 
   SUM(status = 7) AS active, 
   SUM(status = 6) AS inactive, 
   SUM(status = 4) AS deleted
FROM table_detail
WHERE dateTime_updated BETWEEN '2015-09-07 06:00:00' AND '2015-09-11 20:00:00'
GROUP BY user_id;
```